# pandas resample by date, начиная с конечной даты

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, group-by

Как можно разделить датафрейм с помощью метода `resample`, вычитая интервал из `end_date`, а не из `start_date`

```py
import pandas as pd

index = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=10, freq='T')
series = pd.Series(range(10), index=index)

[t for _, t in series.resample('4T')][-1]
```

```
2000-01-01 00:08:00    8
2000-01-01 00:09:00    9
Freq: T, dtype: int64
```

Ожидаю:

```
2000-01-01 00:06:00    6
2000-01-01 00:07:00    7
2000-01-01 00:08:00    8
2000-01-01 00:09:00    9
Freq: T, dtype: int64
```

Разделяет на промежутки 0, 4 и 8 минут. Необходимо, чтобы разделял на промежутки 0, 2, 6 минут (то есть чтобы последним был промежуток длиной `4T`)

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Что-то я не заметил в ваших примерах данных озвученных часов...

Comment: Я вывожу ласт сэмпл, деление именно такое

Answer (score 1):

Можно указать атрибут `offset` в методе `resample`:

```
import pandas as pd
import math

index = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=10, freq='T')
series = pd.Series(range(10), index=index)

interval=4
offset=interval*math.ceil(len(index)/interval)- len(index)

[t for _, t in series.resample(f"{interval}T", offset=f"-{offset}T")]
```

---

```
[2000-01-01 00:00:00    0
 2000-01-01 00:01:00    1
 Freq: T, dtype: int64,
 2000-01-01 00:02:00    2
 2000-01-01 00:03:00    3
 2000-01-01 00:04:00    4
 2000-01-01 00:05:00    5
 Freq: T, dtype: int64,
 2000-01-01 00:06:00    6
 2000-01-01 00:07:00    7
 2000-01-01 00:08:00    8
 2000-01-01 00:09:00    9
 Freq: T, dtype: int64]
```